# Recommended way to set a variable only once in PHP

Tags: php

The use case is as follows:
I have a variable `$roles` which I need to run a DB query to set its value. 
Some of the methods in my class need this `$roles` and some don't need it, so instantiate it in the constructor is not an option.

The question is what is the most elegant way to set its value only once so then the methods that need this variable won't need to check if the value is set and use it right away.

I thought about two options to accomplish it, but both of them don't feel natural.

Option 1 (more procedural way):

```
class DoSomething {
    public function getRoles() {
        static $roles;
        if (!isset($roles)) {
            $roles = do_query_to_the_db_and_give_me_the_roles();
        }
        return $roles;
    }

    public function doX() {
        $roles = $this->getRoles();
    }
}
```

Option 2: (more OOP way)

```
class DoSomething {
    private $roles;

    public function setRoles() {
        $this->roles = do_query_to_the_db_and_give_me_the_roles();
    }

    public function getRoles() {
        if (!isset($this->roles)) {
            $this->setRoles();
        }
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function doX() {
        $roles = $this->getRoles();
    }
}
```

I'm more than happy to hear other approaches.
Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion is to get the roles every time and not worry about it.  Roles are often a key element of a site, so the amount of overhead to lazy load may not be worth it.

Comment: `$roles` was just an example, it can be anything else, and DB query is relatively expensive to do if there is no need.

Comment: What about using a session variable?  Are these large sets of data?  Have you checked to see if you can improve performance of the query?

Comment: The two approaches I described can work without a session, and they don't run the query when there is no need. I'm trying to get a more elegant approach without decreasing the performance.

Comment: Why invent a bicycle again when it's already been invented? And you are trying to invent a bicycle here.

Comment: @Nordenheim  I'm Not sure where you see bicycles here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the marginal performance gain, your class could extend or decorate whatever Cache you're using and make the static a class property, so something like:

```
class Roles {

    private static $roles = [];
    private $cache;

    function __construct(Cache $cache) {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    function getRoles() { 
        if (!self::$roles) { 
            if(!self::$roles = $this->cache->get('roles')) { 
                self:$roles = do_db_query(); 
                $this->cache->set('roles', self::$roles);
            }
        } 
        return self::$roles;
    }
}

$roles = (new Roles(new Cache))->getRoles();
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually I'm not passing any Cache here. I need the `$roles` in this class only. It has no meaning outside of this class. The performance are fine, I just don't want to degrade the performance by instantiate the `$roles` in the constructor.

Comment: @user2023637 - then I'd be surprised if there is any significant performance differences between the two examples you gave, or variances on the same *unless* you're after very small gains. Premature optimization and all that :)

Comment: Agree. I don't think there is any different in terms of performance, and actually I'm not trying to gain anything more in performance. I'm just trying to get the cleanest approach...

Answer (score 0):

Either way is fine.  If you're worried about performance you could cache the roles via memcache for a certain time period and refresh it so often.

Comment: Actually I'm not worried about the performance. It just doesn't seem 'clean' to me. It is much cleaner to have it in the constructor, but I don't want it to be called every time this class is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Roles in creation?  You could pass in cached roles.  Or a role service.

```
class DoSomething
{
    private $roles;

    public function __construct($roles)
    {
         $this->roles = $roles
    }
}
```

Comment: I create the `$roles` in the `DoSomething` class. It has no meaning, and there is no reason for me to create it outside of this class. The use of Roles is just an example, it can be anything else.

Comment: If you have multiple classes that need 'roles', this may be a better approach.

Comment: I have multiple classes that need this class `DoSomething`, some of these classes need the methods that use `$roles`, some of them don't.